How to access the Expert Market as a US citizen?
Supposedly, it's possible to access the Expert Market through full service brokers. However, they require large active accounts trading frequently. I hear Questrade allows any Canadian to for cheap, which is preferable. Is there any means for a US citizen to buy shares from the Expert Market? Is the best option finding a Canadian to contract with and have him place orders for you?

Could swear we saw this question last year, but a quick search isn't finding it ..

I remember it too. Virtually word for word.

I believe this is the forth iteration of the OP trying to figure this out

They're no longer showing up in my account history. According to US regulations I qualify to buy from the Expert Market, but I cannot find anyone offering access to the Expert Market for me.

These are the same types of stocks Warren Buffet used to accumulate the money used to buy Berkshire Hathaway. My understanding is in order to gain access today the person needs to be trading through Canada or have personal connections with the firms operating in this space. Other than that maybe setting up a trust in Canada with the American as the beneficiary.

I edited the questions previously to make them fit the requirements, and they did not get reopened. They have seemed to have disappeared. So, I'm trying to ask it in a way that is allowed. I keep seeing people trying to buy these securities, but it seems nearly impossible to get a clear answer on how.

I think you've answered your own question. You go shopping for a broker who deals with these, and meet whatever their requirements are for being willing to deal with this on your behalf. If they don't think you're going to move enough money to be worth the effort, they don't have to accept you as a customer.
"Expert market" equals extremely high risk. Unless you already have the kind of money to be playing in the venture capital space -- eg, you can afford to lose $100k if the company flops for any reason, and can afford to do the research to find the few that actually have a reasonable chance of succeeding -- this is not a game you can play or should be playing.
You cite Buffet. Websearch the Buffett Bet. Dancing on the razor's edge is neither necessary nor sufficient to get good returns.

Buffet does not follow his own advice. He also has not out performed the indexes over the past 20 years. If he understood computers better he would have. I want to put a small percentage of my portfolio in here. 5% max. The majority of that 5% is going to hedge against currency exchange risk over a foreign stock I own. The rest is speculative to getting out break even on a position I already own. I've been following the price action for the past few months. I could have easily closed out my WeWork position at break even to a slight gain had I been able to buy from the Expert Market.

I also might need access in the future to the Expert Market in order to exercise put options I hold. I bought a bunch of puts on businesses I believe would go bankrupt if there's a recession in the next three years. Bankrupt companies typically move to the Expert Market. Not having the ability to access the Expert Market is the difference between taking a slight loss, profiting a few million, or a few tens of millions. If I cannot access the Expert Market I might have to sell my puts for a loss to a market maker who can, and would exercise for a huge profit.

You really should have researched this before buying those puts, of course. Which is sorta my reaction to the proposed strategy. But de gustibus...

There's clearly a means of accessing the Expert Market. There has to be another option other than renouncing US citizenship and moving across national borders. I literally fit the regulatory requirement for having access.

Evidence so far is that none of the most active posters here has the solution you are looking for. A good answer may yet turn up, but in your shoes I'd start trying to ask in other communities, possibly looking for ones more specifically focused on high-risk trading.

And you may want to consider that, if there aren't brokers actively trying to sell you this service, that's probably because there is too much cost and not enough return to justify their efforts. Which may tell you something about whether you should really be putting more effort into this. Gods know many brokers are perfectly happy to market anything that will make them a profit, whether they think it's a good investment or not.

That's the reason I want to buy. The lack of investors creates market inefficiencies so stocks are far undervalued and have more volitility.

Market inefficiencies can cause overvaluing too.  You're going to have to do a heck of a lot of work to find the companies that are recovering rather than crashing, which is the piece of the puzzle you haven't mentioned -- playing venture capitalist successfully takes serious time and effort. Good luck; my perception is that you are going to need it if you do find a way into that market.

@ZeroPhase Buffett isn't outperforming because he doesn't understand computers, but because he has the largest portfolio in history that limits him to buying only mega cap stocks. When we discuss the expert market, we are talking about the Buffett of the 50s and 60s when he was averaging 40% annualized buying illiquid stocks overlooked by the market.

Yeah, in the 50s and 60s he bought Expert Market type stocks to accumulate the capital he used to buy Berkshire Hathaway. He was able to track people down and get meetings to figure out if their company was valuable.
But, he is not outperforming the market today from avoiding tech investments, as most of the growth over the past 30 years came from those. He missed a lot of excellent companies Silicon Valley venture capitalists got in on during the Dotcom boom. He also missed his chance to accumulate Microsoft early. He does not invest in tech for the most part.
